# Conversion between "pandas.Series" to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas.Series` that every element is a `numpy.array`,
For example:

```py
p = pandas.Series([numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([2,4])])
```

I try to convert the whole `Series` into a multi-dimensional (2,2) `numpy.array`, for that I use `values` method of `Series`, but this one returns a single dimension numpy array that each element in the array is a `numpy.array` and the dtype of the array is `object`:

```py
In [18]: p = pandas.Series([numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([2,4])])

In [19]: p.values
Out[19]: array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 4])], dtype=object)
```

The result that I would like to achieve is as the series would have been created as numpy array

```py
In [23]: a = numpy.array([numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([2,4])])

In [24]: a
Out[24]:
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])

In [25]: a.shape
Out[25]: (2, 2)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to make such a conversion? `to_numpy` method doesn't work also for me.

Comment: Maybe you want to use pandas DataFrame instead of a Series. Series is normally used for one-dimensional data. If you use `pandas.DataFrame([numpy.array([1,2]), numpy.array([2,4])]).values` you should get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following conversion:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p = pd.Series([np.array([1,2]), np.array([2,4])])
np.array(p.values.tolist()).shape
```